# How to get large JSON Using REST template Spring MVC without memory issues in java

Tags: java, spring, out-of-memory, resttemplate

When i get large JSON from REST service i receive java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space...

This is occurs after ~1000 calls the REST service

```
    HttpEntity<ProductRequest> requestUpdate = new HttpEntity<>(request, httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<String> messageEntity = restTemplate.exchange(getEndPointAddress(), HttpMethod.POST, requestUpdate, String.class);

    Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(Helper.cleanJson(messageEntity.getBody()), Map.class);

<pre>
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694) ~[?:1.7.0_181]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203) ~[?:1.7.0_181]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:405) ~[?:1.7.0_181]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copyToString(StreamUtils.java:80) ~[stormjar.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:86) ~[stonjar.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:41) ~[stonjar.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:193) ~[stonjar.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:104) ~[stonjar.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:884) ~[stonjar.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:868) ~[stonjar.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:622) ~[stonjar.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580) ~[stonjar.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:498) ~[stonjar.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.myorg.wcf.PMiddle.retrieveP(PMiddle.java:95) ~[ssar.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.myorg.RetrieveP.getPJsonFromService(RetrieveP.java:188) ~[ssar.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.myorg.RetrieveP.execute(RetrieveP.java:107) ~[ssar.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5044$tuple_action_fn__5046.invoke(executor.clj:727) ~[storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__4965.invoke(executor.clj:459) ~[storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__4480.onEvent(disruptor.clj:40) ~[ss-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:472) ~[ss-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:451) ~[ss-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:73) ~[ss-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5044$fn__5057$fn__5110.invoke(executor.clj:846) ~[ss-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:484) [ss-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.7.0_181]</pre>
```

Comment: so you call something over 1000 times and are keeping all the results or?you may want to save to a file and append after every so many calls.

Comment: I call other service for put resultat json every time

Comment: can you show the loop? can you make just the 1000th request and does that work?

Comment: no this is a large project that calls others services ==> microservices, but after many times (>1000)  give me this exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: can you show the loop

Comment: yes i can show the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RestTemplate` and underlying Spring beans are not designed for stream processing, they build the entire `ResponsEntity` in the memory. Based on your example you are not using `RestTemplate` as intended. You are reading  `String` instead of delegating response object `Map<String, Object>` deserialization to underlying converter bean.

If the JSON response is really too big to fit into your heap you can replace `RestTemplate` with `URLConnection` or any other HTTP client library that will let you access the response `InputStream` directly. This will allow you to manually read and parse the response e.g. [by using `com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader`](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2015/10/23/reading-json-file-in-stream-mode-with-gson.html):

```
URLConnection conn = // create and open
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
// read manually using reader
```

You will be able to save memory that way by avoiding the one big `String` object that holds the entire JSON body.

Comment: thank you for your answer but requestUpdate  contains request  that's an object (class) with attributes and the values because i want to provide params for retrieve results based on given data.