# Springboot RestTemplate - Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-resttemplate

I have two services A and B where Service A is trying to get the `json` data from the Service B. When data is less for example 10KB the call ends without any exception. But when the data is around 100MB it gives an error `java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server` on Service A and we see `Exception Message:java.io.IOException: Broken pipe` in Service B.

We are using
**Spring boot 2.2.6**, **Java8** and **RestTemplate** for communication.
Below is the stackTrace for Service A.

```
java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:862)
java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:859)
java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:82)
org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:109)
org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:93)
org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77)
org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:739)
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:612)
com.TestRestService.getData(TestRestService.java:58)
com.TestRestService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$91579cd4.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:156)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
com.TestRestService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f08eacac.getData(<generated>)
com.TestService.getData(TestService.java:25)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Below the definition of resttemplate in Service A.

```
public RestTemplate restTemplate(final RestTemplateBuilder  builder) {
        return builder
                .requestFactory(new ClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier())
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(15))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(15))
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: This is happening how long after the call? Is it always same?

Comment: Service B is taking less than 2 mins to respond the request. Added definition of resttemplate to the question.

Comment: Is there any error in Service B? Usually this happens when server(Service B) close the connection

Comment: Yes, its 'java.io.IOException: Broken pipe'

Comment: As I get, RestTemplate no disagned for processing big files. Probably you should consider usage of alternative clients which support streaming - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54484348/8312604

Comment: We got the root cause of this issue. We are deploying our applications to cloud environment and it has default route timeout as 30 seconds. 
As request was taking more than 30 seconds, so pod was closing the connection. After increasing the timeout, the issue got resolved. Thank you all for your help/answers.